# How to rename multiple files in Linux?

Tags: linux, rename

I want to rename my files in linux from

```
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-20161127175734_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-20161127175734_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-20161127180331_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-20161127180331_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-20161127173234_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-20161127173234_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-20161127173809_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-20161127173809_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-rest_run-20161127164822_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-rest_run-20161127164822_bold.nii.gz
```

to be

```
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-1_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-1_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-2_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-MID_run-2_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-1_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-1_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-2_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-nBack_run-2_bold.nii.gz
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-rest_run-1_bold.json
sub-NDARINVKW1ALL48_ses-year0120161127_task-rest_run-1_bold.nii.gz
```

Can anyone help?
I have a list of similar files in different directories too. So, I want it to be a generic code that I can use, if possible.

Comment: you can iterate over an loop of files in your folder then rename with SED+REGEX

Comment: what is your pattern for after `run_-` -- part numbers, 1 and 2 where do they come from ?

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri that pattern is just a full date including time of the day. for example, 20161127175734 means that run was in 2016/11/27 at 17:57:34. I just order them based on that time, recent runs get added to the list at the end.

Comment: @MuhammadElsadany I meant the desired output, for example `run-1_bold.nii.gz` the number `1` where does this come form ? Or what is the relation between `run-20161127164822_bold.nii.gz` which turns to `run-1_bold.nii.gz`